# How can I create lists within a loop from a list of strings with each string becoming a separate unique list I can now access in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I want to generate 25 unique lists from a starting list of values within a loop, how can I turn a string list elements into lists in such a way that I can increment every loop and save the new list so that as an end result I have 25 separate lists named list1,list2...list25 that I can access for further use?

In my loop, I have written stringList[count] where I need to create the list from the string list, I know it's incorrect, I just put it there so that it's easy to understand where and what I'm looking for. For example, it should create list1 and copy currentList values to it there on the first loop, then list 2 and so on.

```
stringList = ['list1','list2','list3','list4','list5','list6','list7','list8','list9',
'list10','list11','list12','list13','list14','list15','list16','list17','list18','list19',
'list20','list21','list22','list23','list24','list25']

startingList = [0,1,0,1,0,1]
currentList = []
currentList2 = []
count = 0
for x in range(5):
  if x == 0:
    currentList = list(startingList)
  #code that modifies currentList into a new unique list
  stringList[count] = list(currentList)
  count += 1
  for y in range(5):
    if y == 0:
      currentList2 = list(currentList)
    #code that modifies currentlist2 into a new unique list

    stringList[count] = list(currentList2)
    count += 1
```

Edit : Would something like this work? Never mind, this won't work. I need to turn the string elements of stringList into lists 1 at a time per loop, not all at once.

```
S = "".join([n +'= [];' for n in stringList])
exec(S)
```

Comment: don't use `currentList = startingList` if you want to preserve the initial list, when you do this you are just getting another name to point to the same list. You can use `currentList = startingList[:]` or other alternatives in order to make a copy of the original. Also I suggest you put the new lists in a dictionary when done instead of using exec

Comment: @KGS thanks for the correction on my copying of the the list. Though I still don't understand how I can actually create a new list on each loop. How can I make stringList[count] return a list called list1, rather than the string 'list1"?

Comment: @KSG or rather, how can I create the list and assign it to copy currentList within one line? Something like stringList[count] = [ ] = currentList?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with exec if you really needed to, but it generally is not that useful. I'd suggest you store all the lists in a dictionary instead. Here is a simple example (let's just concentrate on storing the lists and you can figure out the rest; btw the code in your question doesn't run - you have `count += 1` in both loops which produces an `index out of range` error). For the purpose of this example we will create 5 lists, holding their index three times inside of them.

exec:

```
>>>for ind in range(5):
>>>    exec("list{} = [{}]*3".format(ind, ind))

#we created the name as a string but now we have to access it as a variable
#it's a bit clumsy
>>>list2 
Out[2]: [2, 2, 2]
```

dictionary - read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
>>>lists = {}
>>>for ind in range(5):
>>>    lists["list{}".format(ind)] = [ind] * 3

#arguably neater
>>>lists["list2"]
Out[6]: [2, 2, 2]
```